# A finite collection of natural numbers has a largest element.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be a nonempty finite collection of natural numbers. I want to prove that $A$ has a largest element, that is $A$ contains a number $m'$ such that $m'\ge a$ for every element $a$ in $A$.

I defined the set

$$M:=\{n\in\mathbb N:n+1>a,\forall a\in A\}$$

so by Well-ordering principle of $\mathbb N$, there is $m'\in M$ such that $m'\le m$ for all $m\in M$ which implies that $m'+1>a$ or $m'\ge a$ for all $a\in A$. Now while it seems easy that $m'\in A$, I can't show that. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Doing an induction might be more clear and easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One small correction is needed: the set $A$ (**Edit** and M) had better be non-empty. But I suppose this is implicitly assumed here.

**Edit**: In light of @Henning Makholm's comment on the boundedness, let me add that argument here for completeness. Since $A$ is finite, we can
let $a_1,\ldots, a_n$ be the elements of $A$. Then $a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n+1>a_i$
for each $i=1,\ldots, n$, so $a_1+\ldots+a_n\in M$ hence $M\neq \emptyset$.

Anyway, you have concluded that the is an $m'\in M$, hence $m'+1>a$ for all $a\in A$.
In particular, $m'\geq a$ for all $a\in A$. Suppose $m'\neq a$ for any $a\in A$.
Then $m'>a$ for all $a\in A$ (since $m'\geq a$ but $m\neq a$). Furthermore, note
that since $A\neq \emptyset$, there is at least one $a\in A$ with $m'>a\geq 0$, so $m'-1\in \mathbb N$ and $m'>a$ for all $a\in A$. Thus by definition,
$m'-1\in M$. But then $m'-1<m'$, which contradicts that $m'$ was least in $M$.

Comment: At the level of rigor where one would ask for an explicit proof of the claim here, I think arguments involving "$\ldots$" would be considered too hand-wavy.

Comment: Is it possible that we don't use $m'-1$? Since it's assumed that we don't know anything about integers or negative numbers.

Comment: @HenningMakholm do you mean for labeling the elements of the set? To be any more explicit, I would need to know how they are choosing to define a finite set for instance, but your point is taken. I leave it to the OP to decide if it is a valid claim in their context.

Comment: @user486600 to be more careful, I would need to know what your exact axioms are, but surely one of them is that any non-zero natural number has a predecessor (or natural different from $1$, if $0\notin \mathbb N$ for you), and the point being observing $m'>a\geq 0$ is that $m'$ is nonzero, so there is an $m''\in \mathbb N$ with $m''+1=m'$.

Comment: I don't have such a thing in my context(natural numbers), but probably we can assume that!

Comment: @user486600 Well don't assume it; it should follow from the definition somehow. (If it doesn't, then I have no idea how you are defining $\mathbb N$ and it would help to tell us!)

Comment: I don't have enough time now, but tomorrow I will think more on, thank you very much!

Comment: @user1306: No, I mean that you write "$a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n$", which I suspect is too informal for a context where one wants explicit proof of something like this question.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ah I see. Perhaps so, again it is hard to know without more context. (Certainly the better way to write this would be $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$, but it would have to be defined; heck, we would need to know that associativity of addition of natural numbers is even proven.)

Comment: According to my context, I can rewrite your answer as follows:
If $m'>a$ for all $a\in A$, then $m'\neq1$ which implies that $m'>1$. This means that there is a $k\in\mathbb N$ such that $k+1=m'$, so $k<m'$ and $k+1>a$ for all $a\in A$. Therefore $k\in M$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Consider ordering the elements in any which way and running a *find max* algorithm.  Just keep track of the max-so-far as you go, and after a finite number of steps you've checked them all, so your max-so-far is the global max.

Answer (score 1):

Following the logic you already have.

$M$ is a subset of $\mathbb N$

Every subset of non-empty $\mathbb N$ has a smallest element.

The smallest element in M equals the largest element in $A.$

I suppose it is a still an open question that $M$ is non-empty.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is finite and nonempty. It's elements can be listed as $x_1,.... x_n$.  And by Well ordering principal, $A$ has a minimum.  Call it $a$.

The sum $X = \sum x_i$ is finite.  As each $x_i \ge 0$ $X \ge x_j$ for all $j$.  (Let's include $0$ as a natural number.)

So the set $A^- = \{n -X|n \in A\}$ is a set of non-positive numbers and has a minimum number (namely $a - X$).

The set $-A^- = \{-v|v  \in A^-\}$ is a set of non-negative numbers and by the well ordering principal has a minimum element.  Call it $v$. And and it has a maximum element $-\min A^- = X - a$.

So $A^-$ has a maximum element in $-v$ and a minimum in $a -X$.

An $A$ has a maximum element in $X -v$ as well as the minimum in $a$.

Of course, this assumes any finite sum is finite.  Which may be circular.  The basic induction axioms should show you can exhaust anything finite.

Comment: The well-ordering principal does not apply to arbitrary sets of integers! (In fact, in this example, $M$ is unbounded above, so $-M$ certainly does not have a minimum element.)

Comment: Oh, ... I misread what M was meant to be.

Comment: Hmm, I need more work.  I'll get to it.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing doesn't really work, because you can't apply the well-ordering principle without *first* showing that your $M$ is non-empty -- so you need to show that $A$ is bounded, and that itself seems to be roughly as involved as showing that it has a maximal element.

Instead, a way forward would be to forget that $A\subseteq\mathbb N$ specifically and prove generally

> A finite (but nonempty) set $A$ of elements from any totally ordered set contains a largest element.

Badam Baplan's answer gives an informal sketch for how to do that. More formally, you can use induction on $|A|$.

Comment: $A$ is a finite set.

Comment: @user486600: Um, yes it is. I don't think I said it wasn't.

Comment: @HenningMakholm It's not so hard to show M is non-empty; I just added a quick argument to my answer below.